# using preg_match in a variable

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

urlI have a log file that has dates in the 2015-03-10 format. So I am taking that log and trying to put a line break in front of each of those dates because the date signifies the beginning of a new log item/line, and the end of the log item/line has nothing unique to use that as a place to put the line break.

I am trying to use preg_match and am very close to getting it figured out but I am doing something wrong in one of the lines.

Here is the code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$phrase = file_get_contents('url_to_log');
$pattern = '/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})/';
$store = preg_match_all($pattern, $phrase);
$replacement = '<br>'. $store .'';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $phrase);
```

Here is the result of the above code

```
{"type":"success","response":{"data":{"thispage":100,"totalpages":1,"log":"<\/TIT2><\/metadata>]\n
66 08:34:00\tINFO\t[ADMINCGI] XML title update [Eat pizza every night\n<\/TIT2><\/metadata>]\n
66 08:38:23\tINFO\t[ADMINCGI] XML title update [Its not a tumor\n<\/TIT2><\/metadata>]\n
66 08:42:45\tINFO\t[ADMINCGI] XML title update [Title of a random music track\n<\/TIT2><\/metadata>]\n
66 08:48:38\tINFO\t[ADMINCGI] XML title update [Title of stuff Random\n<\/TIT2><\/metadata>]\n
```

I am sure you notice that the 2015-03-10 format, is being replaced by 66, instead of the date that was originally there with a line break just appended to the front of it.

What am I missing?

Comment: *preg_match_all() Return Values: Returns the number of full pattern matches (which might be zero), or FALSE if an error occurred.* so you got 66 matches, no go see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) for what you should be doing

Comment: Also, `json_decode`, loop and prepend, `json_encode`.

Comment: I am looking through those things and trying various things, but am not having much success. Do you have an example of something sort of like what I am trying to do that may give me that push in the right direction?

Comment: I am still stuck on this even though I think I am very close. I have done the json decode, then tried doing a foreach loop with no success, and also tried putting the results into an array to grab the title. Anyone have any ideas?